# How to store checked item in an array in reactjs using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to filter a list of item using checkbox and I have no idea how to implement this. The Way I did is defnitly not working.Can Anyone please help me to fix this.

Here is my code

```
class CartItems extends  React.Component {
  state ={
    cart: [],
    checkedValue: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({
        cart: [...this.props.cart]
      });
  }

  handleCheckboxChange = (event) => {
      //TODO: Checkbox
      this.setState({
        checkedValue: this.state.checkedValue.concat([event])
      })
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Checked Value', this.state.checkedValue);

    return (
    this.props.cart.map(item => (
      <Grid
        style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #d2d2d2" }}
        container
        className="margin15"
      >

        <Grid container spacing={16} justify="center" className="cart">
          <Grid container justify="flex-end" item xs={1}>
            <Checkbox
                onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
                style={{ padding: "0px" }}
            />
          </Grid>
```

When i console log the checked value i get something like this.
[image: im]

any one please help me to solve I have no idea how to implement checkbox item.
I have list of item and i want to filter the item that are checked. And I am unable to figure out how to do this.
[image: image3]

Comment: you shoud pass event.target.value not just event i think :D

Comment: when i pass `event.target.value` it gives me `[" ", " " ]`  only.

Comment: event.target.checked for checkbox , try this out :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the state of check item as true or false initially
Once you click the checkbox the function handleCheckboxChange runs.

```
 handleCheckboxChange=(e)=>{ this.setState({data: !this.state.data}) }
```

You can then store this state of data wherever you want.

I tried this in one of my projects and it works fine:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)    
    this.state = {
        fb:                    false
    }
}
fbChange=(e)=>{ this.setState({fb: !this.state.fb}) }
```

in render

```
{ this.state.posts.map(( i, index ) => { return (
....
<label><input type="checkbox" checked={JSON.parse(i.socialAccounts[0])} onChange={this.fbChange}/>Facebook</label>
.....
)})}
```